# How to get simple product id using custom js in Magento2?

Tags: javascript, magento2.2, jquery, wishlist, php-7

If I have a configurable product and I select color red, then how can I get the alert- id of that virtual product that has been selected?

I would need to do this each time when a new color is selected on the Wishlist  page to get the id of the new selected virtual product.

**custom.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/url'
], function ($,_, url) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('ajaxcart.customWishlist', {
        options: {
            bindSubmit: true,
            addToCart: '[data-role=to-cart]',
            dataAttribute: 'item-id',
            dataAttributeId: 'product-id',          
            dataAttributeUrl: 'url',
            TypeAttribute: 'product-type',
            nameFormat: 'Size[{0}]',
            colorFormat: 'Color[{0}]',
            size: '',
            color: '',
            producttype: '',
            productId: '',
            url: '',
            configUrl: '',
            checkoutUrl: ''
        },
        /**
         * Uses Magento's validation widget for the form object.
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {

            if (this.options.bindSubmit) {
                this._bindSubmit();
            }
        },
        _bindSubmit: function () {
            var self = this;

            this.element.on('click', "#wishlist-cartsubmit", $.proxy(this._beforeAddToCart, this))
        },
        submitHandler: function (elem) {
            var self = this;

            var size = this.options.size;
            var color = this.options.color;
            var producttype = this.options.producttype;

            if (producttype === 'configurable')
            {
                var productid = this.options.productId;
                var configlink = this.options.configUrl;

                var checkouturl = this.options.checkoutUrl;
                $.ajax({
                    url: configlink,
                    type: "POST",
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: {product: productid, size: size, color: color},
                    success: function (response) {
                         window.location =  checkouturl;


                    }
                });
            }
            if (producttype === 'simple') {

                var urllink = this.options.url;
                console.log(urllink);
                var obj = urllink;
                var action = obj.action;
                var dataobj = obj.data;
                var itemid = dataobj.item;
                var qty = dataobj.qty;
                var uenc = dataobj.uenc;
                 var checkouturl = this.options.checkoutUrl;
                var formKey = jQuery("input[name='form_key']").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url: action,
                    data: {item: itemid, qty: qty, uenc: uenc, form_key: formKey},
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (response) {
                      window.location = checkouturl;

                    }

                });
            }

        },
        _beforeAddToCart: function (event) {
            var self = this;
            var elem = $(event.currentTarget),
                    productType = elem.data(this.options.TypeAttribute);

            this.options.producttype = productType;
            if (productType == "configurable")
            {
                alert("config");
                var productId = elem.data(this.options.dataAttributeId)
                this.options.productId = productId;

                //var itemId = elem.data(this.options.dataAttribute),
                       // sizeName = $.validator.format(this.options.nameFormat, itemId),
                        //sizeValue = elem.parents().find('[name="' + sizeName + '"]').val();

                //this.options.size = sizeValue;
                var item = elem.data(this.options.dataAttribute),
                        colorName = $.validator.format(this.options.colorFormat, item),                        
                        colorValue = elem.parents().find('[name="' + colorName + '"]').val();


                this.options.color = colorValue;
            }
            if (productType == "simple")
            {
                var dataurl = elem.data(this.options.dataAttributeUrl)
                this.options.url = dataurl;
                alert(this.options.url);
            }
            self.submitHandler($(this));
        }

    });
    return $.ajaxcart.customWishlist;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add following js Code in bottom of this file  **app/design/frontend/[your_theme_package]/[your_theme]/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml**

```
require(["jquery"], function(jQuery) {
  jQuery(".product-options-wrapper select[id^='attribute']").last().on('change', function() {
      setTimeout(function (){
        simpleId=jQuery("input[name=selected_configurable_option]").val();
        alert(simpleId);
      }, 500); 
  }); });
```

And Clear cache and check.
Please look at this screenshot. It works for me.
[image]

Comment: But i want this alert in wishlist page ....If any idea